# Add multiple Input Fields in single div using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

i am coding a program in javascript for multiple data setting. But i get stuck in code for placing multiple input fileds as per the entered number of input fields.

```js
function createTextFields(nom) {
  alert(nom);
  var count = nom;
  for (var l = 0; l < count.length; l++) {
    document.getElementById('formSet').innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="textField_' + l + '" id="textField_' + l + '" required>';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `+=` to append the new `input` to the `form`.

```js
createTextFields(10);

function createTextFields(nom) {
  var count = nom;
  for (var l = 0; l < count; l++) {
    document.getElementById('formSet').innerHTML += '<input type="text" class="form-control"  placeholder="textField_' + l + '" name="textField_' + l + '" id="textField_' + l + '" required><br/>';
  }
}
```

```html
<form id="formSet"> </form>
```

**Note:** Instead of `count.length` in the `for` condition I put only `count` because you said "entered number" and a `Number` don't have `length` property.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you should not use innerHTML. instead create new elements and add attributes to it. As I have illustrated below:

```
function createTextFields(nom)
        {
            alert(nom);
            var count = nom;
            for(var l = 0; l<count.length;l++)
            {
//              document.getElementById('formSet').innerHTML = '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="textField_'+l+'" id="textField_'+l+'" required>';
                var input = document.createElement("INPUT");    
                input.setAttribute("type", "text");
                input.setAttribute("class", "form-control");
                input.setAttribute("name", "textField_"+l);
                input.setAttribute("id", "textField_"+l);
                input.setAttribute("required", true);
                document.getElementById('formSet').appendChild(input);
            }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

// call funciton createTextFields 
createTextFields(10);

 function createTextFields(nom)
{
    // nom will be a number of elements to be added
    var count = nom;

    var k = new Array();

    for(var l = 0; l <count; l++)
    {
        // push into array
        k.push('<input type="text" class="form-control" name="textField_'+l+'" id="textField_'+l+'" required>');

    }
    // insert those childs to the formset and by joining the array
    // of textfield
    document.getElementById('formSet').innerHTML = k.join('');

}

</script>
```

Feel free to modify the code according to what you need